# Import XYDATA with Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data file

```
XYDATA, Internal Energy
0.0000000000e+00    0.0000000000e+00
5.0005283356e+00    4.6192109585e-03
1.0000238419e+01    1.0114063509e-02
1.5000775337e+01    2.3850044236e-02
...
ENDATA

XYDATA, Kinetic Energy
0.0000000000e+00    0.0000000000e+00
5.0005283356e+00    4.3820664287e-03
1.0000238419e+01    8.0710751936e-03
1.5000775337e+01    3.4025760833e-03
...
```

that I want to import to plot the two columns. I tried to do it with `panda` but it's not working, the output data is composed of one single column. Here's what I tried:

```
data = pd.read_table('file.dat',skiprows=1,nrows=40)
```

Here's the `data.head()` I obtained :

```
   0.0000000000e+00    0.0000000000e+00
0  5.0005283356e+00    4.6192109585e-03
1  1.0000238419e+01    1.0114063509e-02
2  1.5000775337e+01    2.3850044236e-02
3  2.0000486374e+01    3.9014153183e-02
4  2.5000198364e+01    6.1761483550e-02
```

Comment: is the file split into multiple little mini tables?

Comment: Do you mind to show us `data.head()`?

Comment: @Datanovice yes it is!

Comment: @rpanai I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add `delim_whitespace` parameter when you read.

```py
data = pd.read_table('file.dat',
                     skiprows=1,
                     nrows=40,
                     delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: Working fine, thx. Any idea how I can also import the first line as table header?

Comment: Just remove the parameter skiprows=1.

Comment: Not working because the first row does not have the same delimiters